# Windows Subsystem Linux installation gives file system error -2145103860 at launch

Tags: 18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[image: windows subsystem linux launch error dialogue]

I have a company issued Windows 10 development machine which I have Local Administrator rights for but which also is centrally managed and e.g. Windows Store is blocked from downloading and installing apps.

Hence I have tried the manual download and installation of the Ubuntu 18.04 app but when trying to launch it I get a file system -2145103860 error.

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: From where did you download the app?

Comment: I did an offline install from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual

Comment: (it turned out we are using an internal Windows Update site, telling Windows Update to ignore that setting made it talk to Microsoft instead so I could install a functional version.  I'd still like to know what I should make out of the error message though)

Answer (score 1):

1. Extract Ubuntu_1604.2019.523.0_x64.appx into a folder (I used 7zip for extraction).
2. Run Ubuntu.exe inside the extracted folder with administrator rights.

The distribution was successfully installed.

The fix was found at https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3437

Comment: What does the error message mean?